# MariaDB has stopped responding - [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.2

MariaDB service was stopped responding all of a sudden. It was running for more than 5 months continuously without any issues. When we check the MariaDB service status at the time of the incident, it showed as *active (running)* ( `service mariadb status` ). But we could not log into the MariaDB server, each logging attempt was just hanged without any response. All our web applications were also failed to communicate with the MariaDB service. Also, we checked the max_used_connections, and it was below the maximum value.

When we going through the logs, we saw the below error (this had been triggered at the time of the incident).

```
210623  2:00:19 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.2.34-MariaDB-log
key_buffer_size=67108864
read_buffer_size=1048576
max_used_connections=139
max_threads=752
thread_count=72
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1621655 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f4c008501e8
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7f4c458a7d30 thread_stack 0x49000
2021-06-23  2:04:20 139966788486912 [Warning] InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
--Thread 139966780094208 has waited at btr0sea.cc line 1145 for 241.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x55e1838d5ab0 created in file btr0sea.cc line 191
a writer (thread id 139966610978560) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file btr0sea.cc line 1145
Last time write locked in file btr0sea.cc line 1218
```

We could not even stop the MariaDB service using general stopping commands ( `service MariaDB stop`). But we were able to forcefully kill the MariaDB process and then we could get the MariaDB service back online.

What could be the reason for this failure. If you have already faced similar issues please share your experience, what actions you got to prevent such failures (in the future). Your feedback is much much appreciated.

**Our Environment Details are as follows**

Operating system: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7
Mariadb version: 10.2.34-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue on an aws instance (c5a.4xlarge) hosting my database.
Server version: 10.5.11-MariaDB-1:10.5.11+maria~focal

It happened already 3 times occasionnaly. Like you, no possibility to stop the service but reboot the machine to get it working again.

Logs at restart suggest some tables crashed and should be repaired.

Comment: Thanks, Hyaz for the input. We also had to kill the MariaDB service forcefully and restart the service. But still we are unaware of the root cause.

Comment: Are you using Mariadb Columnstore by any chance ? I suspect the issue could come from the  storage engine.

Comment: No, we are not using Columnstore.